# Resolve duplicate issues with while loops and dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, input, while-loop, duplicates

I have a list of items that are determined by what a player enters into several input fields, but for the sake of this example, let's say that it contains "a", "b", "c", "d", and "e". These are then sorted into a dictionary with a list of numbers as the values (unimportant). I then randomize the dictionary with two different randomizer variables (i and j), for the sake of taking two objects from the dictionary and displaying them to the screen, so the player can press various associated buttons. This goes on until x amount of turns have passed. **The main problem** I'm having is the prevention of semi-duplicates, such as "a b" and "b a" from appearing.

I have tried entering inserting both the randomized pair and its semi-duplicate into another dictionary and then using while loop statements preventing any pairs from that dictionary from appearing. Unfortunately, this hasn't worked.

Below is my code.

```
public void Start() {
    finalList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (index = 0; index < allNumbers; index++)
    {
        finalList.Add(itemList[index], valueList[index]);
        Debug.Log(finalList[index.ToString()]);
    }
}
public void Update() {
    choose();
}

public void choose() {
    duplicates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    duplicates.Clear();
    while (rounds < insertNum) {

        key = "(" + itemList[i].ToString() + " " + itemList[j].ToString() + ")";
        reverseKey = "(" + itemList[j].ToString() + " " + itemList[i].ToString() + ")";

        while (j == i || (duplicates.ContainsKey(key) || duplicates.ContainsKey(reverseKey))) {
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, allNumbers - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, allNumbers - 1);
            key = "(" + itemList[i].ToString() + " " + itemList[j].ToString() + ")";
            reverseKey = "(" + itemList[j].ToString() + " " + itemList[i].ToString() + ")";
            Debug.Log("(new keys " + key + ", " + reverseKey + ")");
            //break;
            } while (j == i || (duplicates.ContainsKey(key) && duplicates.ContainsKey(reverseKey)))
            {
                i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, allNumbers - 1);
                j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, allNumbers - 1);
                key = "(" + itemList[i].ToString() + " " + itemList[j].ToString() + ")";
                reverseKey = "(" + itemList[j].ToString() + " " + itemList[i].ToString() + ")";
                Debug.Log("(new keys " + key + ", " + reverseKey + ")");
            }while (j == i && (duplicates.ContainsKey(key) || dupes.ContainsKey(reverseKey))) {
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, allNumbers - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, allNumbers - 1);
            key = "(" + itemList[i].ToString() + " " + itemList[j].ToString() + ")";
            reverseKey = "(" + itemList[j].ToString() + " " + itemList[i].ToString() + ")";
            Debug.Log("(new keys " + key + ", " + reverseKey + ")");

        }
        while (j == i && (duplicates.ContainsKey(key) && duplicates.ContainsKey(reverseKey))) {
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, allNumbers - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, allNumbers - 1);
            key = "(" + itemList[i].ToString() + " " + itemList[j].ToString() + ")";
            reverseKey = "(" + itemList[j].ToString() + " " + itemList[i].ToString() + ")";
            Debug.Log("(new keys " + key + ", " + reverseKey + ")");
        }
        duplicates.Add(key, "1"); // the one is just a filler variable
        duplicates.Add(reverseKey, "1");
        if (buttonOneBool) { //this is in another script, ignore
            finalList[itemList[i].ToString()] = valueList[i] += 2;
            finalList[itemList[j].ToString()] = valueList[j] -= 2;
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
        } else if (buttonTwoBool) {
            finalList[itemList[i].ToString()] = valueList[i] -= 2;
            finalList[itemList[j].ToString()] = valueList[j] += 2;
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
        } else if (buttonThreeBool) {
            finalList[itemList[i].ToString()] = valueList[i] -= 1;
            finalList[itemList[j].ToString()] = valueList[j] -= 1;
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
        } else if (buttonFourBool) {
            finalList[itemList[i].ToString()] = valueList[i] += 1;
            finalList[itemList[j].ToString()] = valueList[j] += 1;
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Order the values and then concatenate them - so "a b" becomes "ab" and "b a" becomes "ab". Then add to a `HashSet`. If `Add` returns `false` then you have seen that combo before and should try again.

Comment: @mjwills Can you explain more about how to set up a hashtable?

Comment: `var g = new HashSet<string>();`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this is to guarantee `i < j`. When selecting a new i and j like this:

`i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max);
 j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max);`

Instead do this:

`i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max - 1);
 j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(i + 1, max);`

Doing this rules out the possibility of selecting a "mirror image" of a previous case and also avoids the "i == j" case.

After these modifications your choose() function should look something like this:

```
    public void choose()
{
    duplicates = new HashSet<string>();
    while (rounds < insertNum)
    {
        key = "(" + itemList[i].ToString() + " " + itemList[j].ToString() + ")";
        while (duplicates.Contains(key))
        {
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, allNumbers - 2);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(i + 1, allNumbers - 1);
            key = "(" + itemList[i].ToString() + " " + itemList[j].ToString() + ")";
        }
        duplicates.Add(key); // the one is just a filler variable

        if (buttonOneBool) { //bool definitions are in another script, ignore
            finalList[itemList[i].ToString()] = valueList[i] += 2;
            finalList[itemList[j].ToString()] = valueList[j] -= 2;
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
        } else if (buttonTwoBool) {
            finalList[itemList[i].ToString()] = valueList[i] -= 2;
            finalList[itemList[j].ToString()] = valueList[j] += 2;
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
        } else if (buttonThreeBool) {
            finalList[itemList[i].ToString()] = valueList[i] -= 1;
            finalList[itemList[j].ToString()] = valueList[j] -= 1;
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
        } else if (buttonFourBool) {
            finalList[itemList[i].ToString()] = valueList[i] += 1;
            finalList[itemList[j].ToString()] = valueList[j] += 1;
            i = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
            j = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n - 1);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the i and j values be changed in the buttonBools section too?

Comment: As per the comment "this is in another script, ignore" i am unsure if those values have the same restrictions.

Comment: Haha, sorry, that was regarding the definition of the bool. Meanwhile, it looks like removing the "j==i" invokes the creation of a lot more duplicates.

Comment: My bad, j should have a minimum value of "i + 1", not "i". This will resolve "j == i" cases.

Comment: It is difficult for me to modify the button cases as the control flow is difficult to follow. The outer while loop for example is guaranteed to run at most once because of the break statement at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure where else to put it, because when I take it out, Unity freezes and becomes unresponsive.

Comment: That's not surprising. Should you be incrementing "rounds" inside the loop somewhere?

Comment: The rounds are increased in the same script as the button bools. That script has a series of functions attached to the various buttons, which simply flip a series of bools to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

You can get two random indexes to a list using code below.  The code uses integer as the list type and will work with any type.

```
List<int> randomList = itemList.Select((x, i) => new { index = i, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.index).ToList();
```

Then the two random indexes into the list are randomList[0] and randomList[1].  The code assigns a random number to each index i of the list.  To get the two items from the list use itemList[randomList[0]] and itemList[randomList[1]].  The code assumes there are at least two items in the original list ItemList[].

If your original list has duplicates than you need to use Distinct() as shown in code below

```
        List<int> distinctList = itemList.Distinct().ToList();
        List<int> randomList = distinctList.Select((x, i) => new { index = i, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.index).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you clarify this? My problem isn't that I'm having trouble getting random indexes.

Comment: Why do you need indexes?  My code randomizes the values in the list.

Comment: I want it so that I can get 'a b' and not 'b a', but I also want to be able to get 'a c', so taking 'a' out of the list prematurely doesn't work

Comment: Once you randomize using my method you only run the algorithm once.  Then the 1st player is index 0, the 2nd player is index 1, the 3rd player is index 2.   You also need to build a schedule of games like 1 - 2, 1 - 3,  2 - 3 with numbers being players.  Then you assign randomly a player to a number so 'a' is player 2, 'b' is player 1, and 'c' is player 3.

Comment: so, just for clarity's sake, if I run the program once, and get a list of outcomes, and then I run it again, the list will be the same?

Comment: The list will be different every time the app is run.  The randomizer has a seed that is derived from the time the app is run which causes the results to be different every time.  If you put an integer into the constructor for the randomizer then you would get the same sequence every time for the same integer.  Changing the integer in the constructor will give a different sequence.  Calling the randomizer constructor with no integer the time is inserted into the constructor.

Comment: Hey there. I'm coming back to this project after a lengthy hiatus, and I've changed up my code a bit to implement the line in your response. However, I still unfortunately get duplicates. I think this might have to do with the fact that I haven't "scheduled my games". When you said this, did you mean that I have to predetermine each of the 10 rounds? And how would I go about doing this via code?

Comment: To prevent duplicates you must create an array of N numbers and then randomize the array.  Use code like following :             int n = 100;
            int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, n - 1).ToArray();
            Random rand = new Random();
            int[] randomNumbers = numbers.Select(x => new { x = x, random = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.random).Select(x => x.x).ToArray();

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something, because I still get duplicates, _and_ I get "Array index is out of range". Here is the code I'm currently using 'System.Random rand = new System.Random();
            num = 100;
            int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, num - 1).ToArray();
            randomListSelect = numbers.Select(x => new { x, random = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.random).Select(x => x.x).ToArray();
            randomList = contList.Select((v, randomListSelect) => new { index = randomListSelect, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(v => v.rand).Select(v => v.index).ToList();'

Comment: You are generating two sets of random numbers.  The first set is my code which doesn't have duplicates.  The seconds random generator has duplicates.  rand = rand.Next()

Comment: Now I'm using the first set of code you gave me, but I'm still getting duplicates (there are no duplicates in the entered data, only the results of the rand). Is it because I'm using the following as my pair-maker?

`choice1 = itemList[randomList[0]];
choice2 = itemList[randomList[1]]`

Comment: Your pair make is fine.  Item 0 and item 1 will always be different.  It is your looping.  If you want unique  pairs the take 0 and 1, then take 2 and 3, then 4 and 5 until you take N/2 pairs.  So you for loop should be for(int i = 0, i < N; i += 2).  Then your two choices are i and (i + 1).